# Avplayer showing black screen sometimes but sound is fine

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using AVPlayer with AVPlayerViewController. I am playing video after adding watermark in the video. Sometimes it is working fine, but sometimes it shows only a black screen, and audio is fine in both cases.

```
vPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_videoFilePath];
// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
controller.player = vPlayer;
[vPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

// show the view controller
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[vPlayer play];
controller.view.frame =_imgForVidFrame.frame;
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Comment: is this iOS10? have you tried the iOS10.1 beta?

Comment: yes, I am working on iOS10, not tried on 10.1

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary have you find the answer?

Comment: @PankajGupta not exactly, but I did some changes in the same code, which is better then last one: '// show the view controller
    controller.view.frame =_imgForVidFrame.frame;
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [vPlayer play];'

Comment: I've faced the same problem and posted about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808377/avplayerlayer-shows-black-screen-but-sound-is-working). Are you facing this issue with local and/or remote videos?

Comment: @ViktorGardart I was working with local video add a sound which is downloaded from URL, then merge with video then play. Now it is working fine, but sometimes, it shows the black screen only on which device has low memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `_imgForVidFrame.frame` is returning correct frame everytime! You can put breakpoint to that line to check that it is returning proper size or not!

and your last line should be `[self.view addSubview:controller.view];` not `controller.view.frame =_imgForVidFrame.frame;` so swap it!

**Update :**

then you can do something like below withou `AVPlayerViewController`,

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_videoFilePath];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player play];
```

or you can present `AVPlayerViewController` something like,

```
 AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_videoFilePath];
 AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
 playerViewController.player = player;
 [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Frame is correct coz, player is visible at expected position. I think there is some problem with avplayer, sometimes it works perfectly.

Comment: I want video in a particular frame, but by these, unable to set frames

Comment: try to set your desired frame instead of `playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;` in first solution!!