# AVPlayerLayer shows black screen but sound is working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

Im trying to display a local recorded video in a **AVPlayerLayer** which works *sometimes*. I can hear the audio from the recorded video but can't see the video. Sometimes both video and audio is working, sometimes only audio.

I've tried both with a **AVPlayerLayer** and **AVPlayerViewController** but the same issue occurs in both cases. So it's not because of the frames being wrong.

Example code **AVPlayerViewController**:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player

self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
  player.play()
}
```

Example code **AVPlayerLayer**:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player!)
self.playerLayer?.frame = imageView.bounds
imageView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
```

Edit 1:

When observing the status of the player, **error** is `nil` and the **status** is `readyToPlay`

Edit 2:

Works fine if the URL is remote.

Edit 3:

Seems to work if I wait a couple of seconds after the video has completed the export. Could it be something to have with the file not 100% written to the filesystem?

Edit 4:
[Video](http://sendvid.com/gbwjeytn) of the problem, in this case it played the 3rd time.

Comment: Show the export code.

Comment: Export code can be found here.

http://pastebin.com/aiSvV6i8

Comment: So there are _multiple_ videos?

Comment: @matt right, multiple videos, exported to one video. And then I'm trying to display the exported video, which works. sometimes.. And if I'm uploading it to our S3 i can perfectly fine view the video.

Comment: Yes, I see. And you are waiting until you get `cameraDidFinishExportingVideo`?

Comment: @matt yes, when the export is completed I'm closing a ViewController and displaying another one. Which previews the exported video.

Comment: Perhaps the problem has to do with how precisely you respond to `cameraDidFinishExportingVideo` and what you do in the next view controller. But you have not shown any of that.

Comment: @matt added a video of the problem to the description. Hope it describes the issue better than i did.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I set a AVPlayerLayer with the video working (I think what you're missing is the `videoGravity` parameter).

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let moviePath = bundle.path(forResource: "myVideo", ofType: "mp4")
let moviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath!))

playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: moviePlayer)
playerLayer.frame = movieView.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
movieView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
playerLayer.player?.play()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said, it's working sometimes. And always if the video is form a remote URL. 

And since it's the same issues in the AVPlayerViewController I'm assuming it's not because of that.

Comment: Amazingly this seems to have fixed my problem on tvOS. Stranger things happen. :o). Thanks.

Comment: Pls suggest here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745359/avplayer-shows-black-screen-when-playing-multiple-videos-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 1):

It's the frame height or width is equal to zero

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issues as you did. the reason is in iOS 10.xx , if you export video with animationTool .
You will meet the trouble like that .
try to fix them by remove this code .

something like that

```
 mainComposition.animationTool =  AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentlayer)
```

Hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

What caused this issue for me was I was changing assets to play a new video. The problem was I was reinitializing the same AVPlayer and setting setting it to the playerLayer which was previously set

Incorrect

```
player = AVPlayer()
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
// ...
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

Correct

```
if player == nil {

    player = AVPlayer()
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    // ...
}

player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```

Or better yet I should've just called this by itself

```
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
```